# Few DTO classes inside one DTO file

Tags: typescript, nestjs, backend, dto

My question is simple: is it a bad practice to keep few DTOs inside one file? For example, I have a project, where few similar DTOs are used for typing:

```
export class CreateGenreDto {
  readonly nameRu: string;
  readonly nameEn: string;
}

export class GenreByIdDto {
  genreId: number;
}

export class UpdateGenreMessageDto extends GenreByIdDto {
  updateGenreDto: CreateGenreDto;
}

export class CreateGenreMessageDto {
  createGenreDto: CreateGenreDto;
}
```

For me it seems kinda annoying for eyes to have four individual files for each of DTOs.

I didn't found any information about it, so is it OK, to instead of this project structure:

```
/app
-/src
-/dto
--create-genre.dto.ts
--genre-by-id.dto.ts
--update-genre-message.dto.ts
--create-genre-message.dto.ts
```

use something like this, storing all similar DTO's in one file?

```
/app
-/src
-/dto
--genres.dto.ts
```

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many experts in user interface / user experience are familiar with Jakob's Law, which states "Users spend most of their time on other sites."

Stealing from this, I would argue that it doesn't matter what you think, or what I think. What matters is what most developers are used to and will expect. The standard is to separate them into separate files. There are reasons for this, and some/all of these reasons might apply to your project, but ultimately whether it's collective wisdom or collective folly doesn't matter nearly as much as what we're used to... and what *future-you* will therefore learn to expect... when glancing through the code.

So maybe you should put them in a `genres` subfolder, but they "should" be separate files.

That said, working code beats unfinished code no matter how perfect it may be. Don't worry about it *too* much. It will run fine either way!

(Advice you *didn't* ask for... Consider defining types and interfaces instead of classes. Every time I use a class, I start wanting to add methods, and then I paint myself into corners. Types and interfaces help me avoid that, and are zero-overhead at runtime.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It's very nice to read such structured point:)